# How to have 2 select query in one function?

Tags: python, mysql, select, flask

I want to have two select query in one function both at the same time.

In shop.html:

```
{% for each in result %}
    {{ each }}<br>
{% endfor %}


{% for each in result2 %}
    {{ each }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

In app.py:

```
@app.route('/shop/<data>')
def shop(data):
    db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","myusername","mypassword","mydbname" )

    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor2 = db.cursor()


    query_string = "SELECT * from users"  
    query_string2 = "SELECT * from people"  


    cursor.execute(query_string)
    cursor2.execute(query_string2)


    result = cursor.fetchall()
    result2 = cursor.fetchall()

    db.close()


    return render_template('shop.html', result=result, result2=result2)
```

But it doesn't work. It just get and prints the first select query.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Your code works just fine; are you *certain* that the second select query returns any data? In other words, have you tried executing *just* the second query, or tried to see what happened when you swapped them around?

Comment: yes each query works well but not when they are both in one function to gather.

Comment: Yes, you have a typo. The second call should be `result2 = cursor2.fetchall()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried to fetch from **one** of the cursors twice:

```
result = cursor.fetchall()
result2 = cursor.fetchall()
```

Note that you called `cursor.fetchall()` in *both cases*. You wanted the second result to come from the second cursor:

```
result = cursor.fetchall()
result2 = cursor2.fetchall()
```

Comment: Yes right, just was a little mistake.